# xcode - copy a folder structure into my app bundle

Tags: xcode

I have a folder structure 10 deep or so. I need to copy that full structure into my app resource folder. Is there an easier way than manually recreating it with 100s of copy phases for each of the folders?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you add a directory to Xcode, there is a tickbox (on by default) to convert folders into groups.

Turn that off, and it will do what you want.

Comment: So would this step copy the whole directory structure like folder reference ?

Comment: @Alix if you select "convert folders into groups", then Xcode will recursively iterate the directory, creating "groups" for every folder and adding every file as a reference. If you deselect it, then Xcode adds a reference to the directory itself.

Comment: In Xcode 9, it is "create folder references" that does this.

Comment: Thanks! This worked - just select "create folder references" and you can see the folder added in the 'Copy Bundle Resources' in Build Phases in Xcode

Answer (score 6):

It is still the same in Xcode 12: Check the ***Create folder references*** box when adding the root folder of your folder structure to the project.

[image: Group hierarchy in project navigator - before]

[image: Source folder hierarchy in Finder]

[image: Add files to folder]

[image: Group hierarchy in project navigator - after]

[image: Resulting folder hierarchy in-app bundle]

To access the resources in code, specify the subdirectory path in your call to `Bundle.url()`:

```swift
Bundle.main.url(forResource: "blabla",
                withExtension: "txt",
                subdirectory: "A/B/C/D")
```

Comment: Then, how do you get path to those files in Swift ?

Comment: You will need to supply the path to the sub-folder. I extended my answer by an example.