# Resources with identical names in the main bundle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, resources, mainbundle

In an iOS app, I happen to have audio resources and it is natural for the use case to call two different resources "001.mp3" and put them in two different folders: Folder_1 and Folder_2. Resulting in:

```
Folder_1/001.mp3
Folder_2/001.mp3
```

But the problem is that Xcode does not like it.

I get an error message like:

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/.../001.mp3':
1) Target 'MYAPP' (project 'MYAPP') has copy command from '../Folder_1/001.mp3' to '.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MYAPP.app/001.mp3'
2) Target 'MYAPP' (project 'MYAPP') has copy command from '../Folder_2/001.mp3' to '.../Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MYAPP.app/001.mp3'
```

Is it impossible for me to have this kind of situation?
(In which case I need to find some work around)

Or is there some specific way to handle this case?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9551237/1187415

Comment: Yes indeed, as simple as it is. It works. Thanks for this tip.